# Get the selected <a> link from a bootstrap dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How can I get a selected  link (not options) from a bootstrap dropdown using jquery?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rank</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="menu_rank">
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-10</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-20</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-30</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-40</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-50</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-60</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item">top 1-70</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The number of link items `<a>` will keep changing by my D3 manipulation.

Comment: Maybe something like: `$('a').on('click', function(e) {console.log($(this).val())})`

Comment: the link <a> is dynamically added (and will change) from my d3 manipulation.

Comment: Then you'll need to phrase your click-targeting differently, point it to the parent & it should pickup dynamically added children: `$('#menu_rank').on('click', 'a', function(e) {console.log($(this).val())})` also, avoid using the same class `dropdown-menu` on the parent and the children, that's a recipe for confusion.